# Slimbox2 displays overlay behind the gallery only on iPad

Tags: c#, ipad, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce, slimbox

When opening the site, in portrait, once clicked on a gallery image, the image is displayed behind the gallery. However once i switched the position of the iPad to landscape it appears normal. On normal browsers and mobile the gallery appears OK. 
Not sure why there is a problem, as the CSS seems to be OK, I've included z-index:999.

```
    <div class="picture @if (Model.PictureModels.Count > 1){<text>col-xs-9</text>}">

        @if (Model.DefaultPictureZoomEnabled)
        {

            <a href="@Model.DefaultPictureModel.FullSizeImageUrl" data-gallery="lightbox-p" title="@Model.Name"  id="main-product-img-lightbox-anchor-@Model.Id">
                <img alt="@Model.DefaultPictureModel.AlternateText" src="@Model.DefaultPictureModel.ImageUrl" title="@Model.DefaultPictureModel.Title" itemprop="image" id="main-product-img-@Model.Id" />
            </a>
            <div class="zoom">
                <a href="@Model.DefaultPictureModel.FullSizeImageUrl" data-gallery="lightbox-p" title="@Model.Name" class="zoom-link">+</a>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <img alt="@Model.DefaultPictureModel.AlternateText" src="@Model.DefaultPictureModel.ImageUrl" title="@Model.DefaultPictureModel.Title" itemprop="image" id="main-product-img-@Model.Id" />
        }
```

Here some code of the Image gallery, If you need any further info, please ask and i will edit my question for you.

Comment: Can you post link to your site?